# Find and join lines in several lines

Tags: notepad++

I want to select lines terminated by `<h2>` and `</h2>` and want to join these lines as shown below:

**Existing Text:**

```
<h2>
A musician's tattoo
</h2>

If you’ re a musician and would like tolket a tattoo, get a tattoo of your ...

<h2>
A zombie hare chest tattoo
</h2>

100/lO0.002.jpg
You won’ tsee this tattoo every day.

<h2>
Abby Name Tattoos
</h2>

For your little angels, a tattoo of their names will never be a mistake.
```

**Desired Text:**

```
<h2>   A musician's tattoo   </h2>

If you’ re a musician and would like tolket a tattoo, get a tattoo of your ...

<h2>   A zombie hare chest tattoo   </h2>

100/lO0.002.jpg
You won’ tsee this tattoo every day.

<h2>   Abby Name Tattoos   </h2>

For your little angels, a tattoo of their names will never be a mistake.
```

I'm using RegEx `<h2>*?.*?</h2>` but only one line is marked.

Comment: Please _remove_ the external image links and instead include the sample input and output directly in your question as _text_, formatted with four or more spaces on each line to make it readable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). See my edits done for you how this works.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(<h2>)\R(.+)\R(.+)`
- Replace with: `\1\2\3`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(<h2>)  : <h2> into group 1
\R      : any kind of linebreak
(.+)    : matches any character into group 2 (except for line terminators)
\R      : any kind of linebreak 
(.+)    : matches any character into group 3 (except for line terminators)
```

If you really want to insert spaces before and after your `H2` text, you have to do this before and after `\2` in Replace with. For clean HTML this makes no sense.

Comment: Groups 2 & 4 are useless and slow down the process.